# Is there a way to randomly select an element of an array, but only if that element passes a certain test?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, random

I have a 2d Boolean array, e.g.

```
bool[,] array = new bool[,] {
  { false, false, true},
  { true, false, false},
};
```

and I want to pick a *random element* that is `false` and switch it to `true`. I've been searching around and can't seem to find a way to *not include* the `true` elements in the random selection.

I'm not too familiar with all the terminology, so I may have just missed an obvious solution.

I know it's possible to randomly select an element, check if it's false, and if it's not then try again until the selected element *is* false, but that potentially could repeat several times in *large arrays* with *very few* `false` elements.

Comment: find all the false elements and select a random one to flip

Comment: maintain a set of just those index pairs which are false. Every time you select a value, flip the bit it points to and remove it from the set.

Comment: In that case, the set is essentially the true/false itself, i.e. false if the index (well, index pair since it's a 2D array) exists, true if it doesn't.

Comment: why do you even care fr a specific element? It sounds you have more data than just a bool, otherwise it won't matter which of the bools you set

Comment: +1; An interesting problem to be solved in *general case* when we have a *large array* and want to solve the problem in *linear time* without creating any collections (i.e. with constant space)

Comment: @pm100 That's what I'm trying to do, I'm just not sure how to actually do it.

Comment: IMHO generate a random permutation, then walk through the list till you find a matching element. That way, if all elements fail the test, you will test each item once.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this example will get you started.

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var rand = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());

        var myArray = new[]
        {
            new Thing() { IsSet = false},
            new Thing() { IsSet = false},
            new Thing() { IsSet = true},
            new Thing() { IsSet = true},
            new Thing() { IsSet = false},
        };

        var trues = myArray.Where((thing) => thing.IsSet).ToArray();
        var randomSelection = trues[rand.Next(0, trues .Length)];
    }
}

class Thing
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public bool IsSet { get; set; }
}
```

Basically, first filter your results to the ones you want to select randomly from using `Where`, and then perform the random selection from those results.

Comment: The question said a **2-dimensional** array.

Comment: The title indicates that the number of dimensions of the array are irrelevant.  But re-reading the body of the question, I'm not 100% sure that is the case, i.e. you may be right.

Comment: After changing a few things this seems to work, but I have a few questions.     
 
1. What is the `Guid` doing in the code? Everything seems to work without it. Also the line `new Guid().GetHashCode()` gives me the same result each time instead of a random one so I removed it and everything worked fine.     

2. Is there a way to do this without creating a class and using instances of that class in the array? My array is just a Boolean array, but using that doesn't work.

Comment: @Druby I just fixed a mistake with the guid 2 mins ago, so if you refresh you can see that.  You're right it would produce the same value the way I had it before, because using the constructor on Guid produces a GUID with all 0s.

Comment: @Druby As for why I need to use the Guid at all, it's providing a random seed to the random number generator.  If you were to use the same value, it would produce the same result every time, as computers actually use *pseudo*-random number, i.e. they use a table of randomly-generated numbers since they're not capable of actually producing random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem in *general case* we should first find the random index; we
can do it with a help of *reservoir sampling*:

```
// Either random index within source
// or -1 if source is empty
public static int RandomIndex<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, 
                                 Func<T, bool> selector = default, 
                                 Random random = default) {
  if (source is null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
  if (selector is null)
    selector = item => true;

  random ??= Random.Shared;

  int result = -1;
  int index = -1;
  int count = 0;

  foreach (var item in source) {
    index += 1;

    if (selector(item))
      if (random.Next(++count) == 0)
        result = index;
  }

  return result; 
}
```

Then having a `bool[,]` array

```
bool[,] array = new bool[,] {
  { false, false, true},
  { true, false, false},
};
```

we can find random index, and if it's valid apply it:

```
int index = RandomIndex<bool>(array.Cast<bool>(), item => !item);

// if array has at least one false item
if (index >= 0)
  array[index / array.GetLength(1), index % array.GetLength(1)] = true;
```

Please, note that solution wants scan the array just once (`O(n * m)` time complexity) and doesn't create any collections (`O(1)` space complexity)

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oBwlCL)

Comment: Although reservoir sampling makes sense mathematically, it greatly increases the entropy required from your pseudo-random number generator.  In **practice**, this will produce a less uniform distribution than if you had counted the matching elements and selected one of them with a single call to random.Next.   Unfortunately the bias is predictable and slightly decreases the probability that lower numbers (items earlier in the array) will be randomly selected.  The distribution stops looking flat and starts looking like the y=sqrt(x) curve. It's minor, but do not use for online gambling games.